# Problem with marginnote

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

I tried to define (my first! - I'm a LateX newbie) command to insert notes in the margins of my text, but it introduces gaps wherever I insert the command :-( The code for my command is:

```
\newcommand{\mnote}[1]
{
  \mbox{}\marginnote{\color{red}\footnotesize#1}
}
```

And I use it for example like this:

```
\subsection{Differentiable Manifold}
\mnote{This is the central object in differential geometry.}A differentiable manifold is
```

but lo and behold, this has the unpleasant effect of adding white space before the letter of the paragraph:

[image: The initial "A" is no longer properly aligned]

How can I restore proper alignment for the initial letter of the paragraph?

Comment: Hmm - it looks like I might have found the answer: starting \mbox on a new line after { seems to be the culprit in the definition of the command... Is that correct?

Comment: Yep. Try {% - newline and #1}% - newline. That is, use comment signs at the ends of newlines where you don't want spaces. A newline is a space to TeX. Like a blank line is a new paragraph.

Comment: @egreg As a "duplicate" we denominate a question, which has been asked before. You are expanding the term to questions, which have the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand{\mnote}[1]
{%
  \mbox{}\marginnote{\color{red}\footnotesize#1}%
}
```

TeX reads a newline as a space, just as it reads a blank line as a paragraph break. Using a comment sign (`%`) removes the newline/space, as far as TeX is concerned, while still allowing you to format the source code in a way which is easy to read.